# Why do I get IndexOutOfBoundsException error in lowpass-filter loop?

Tags: java, filter, signal-processing

I am trying to implement the Pan Tompkins algorithm in my first Java application. I have made the following loop for the lowpass-filter, based on the original article but I keep getting IndexOutOfBoundsException error when I try to run it. Can someone see where I go wrong?

I don't want to make the filter with coefficients, I just need help to get the formula to work, please.

```
/**
 * Lowpass filter
 * lpfilt() implements the digital filter represented by the difference equation:
 * y(nT) = 2y(nT - T) - y(nT - 2 T) + x(nT)- 2x(nT- 6T)+x(nT- 12T)
 */

public static ArrayList<Double> lpfilter(ArrayList<Double> ecg) {
    int N = ecg.size();

    ArrayList<Double> ecgLP = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
        if (n - 12 < 0) {
            ecgLP.set(n, ecg.get(n));
        } else {
            ecgLP.set(n, 2 * ecgLP.get(n - 1) - ecgLP.get(n - 2) + ecg.get(n) - 2 * ecg.get(n - 6) + ecg.get(n - 12));
        }
    }
    return ecgLP;
}
```

Comment: You need to use `add` instead of set, at least when n < 12

Comment: I dont know about algo but seems condition in if is reversed by mistake, probably you wanted to write if (n - 12 > 0) or if (n - 12 >= 0)

Comment: Thank you both! Very helpful comments :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens in the first iteration. Look at the following line:

```
ecgLP.set(n, ecg.get(n));
```

For n=0 you try to set the key 0 with with a value of ecg.get(0). But 0 has not been set so far. Therefore you get the IndexoutofBounds-Error. As far as I see the first 12 (0..11) iterations should fill the ArrayList, but your code will fail with errors every time because you try to use a member which has not been initialized yet.

I would suggest you do the initialisation in a separate loop and start with n=12 afterwards.

Comment: Hey Melvin! Thanks, that actually makes a lot of sense. I will try to add an initialization loop for the first 12 indices.

Answer (score 1):

In for loop take case when n is 0, in this case you can not call ecgLP.get(n - 1) as it becomes ecgLP.get(-1), negative index gives you Exception.